# Where to submit own html, css, javascript tutorials?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am planing to start writing tutorials on html, css and javascript. This year has been full of extremely interesting experience in this areas, so I wish to start on.

Therefore, I wish to know the best places to submit my tutorials before publishing them elsewhere.
I found just one very nice place: http://net.tutsplus.com/about/write-a-tutorial/ so far...

**Right now here's a list of websites I know to submit tuts:**

- http://net.tutsplus.com/about/write-a-tutorial/
- http://www.alistapart.com/contribute/
- http://sixrevisions.com/
- http://pixel2life.com/
- http://tutorialized.com/
- http://cmstutorials.org/
- http://smashingmagazine.com/
- https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/marketing/blog/unfiltered/

Exciting list collected from user answers to this question is already food enough!
However, asking for more suggestions?!

Comment: Make your own website? It will have the added benefit of establishing your presence in the developer community.

Comment: @Delan, I have already, just need to refresh it a little bit!

Comment: The great thing is that when I started my website on January this year, merely a few months in, I've had a few freelance article writing offers, which is quite nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just start your own blog. If you write good tutorials people will find it eventually :)

Comment: Not to mention that if they are any good, other sites will pick them up as well.

Answer (score 3):

http://sixrevisions.com is also a good place to write, they have over 65000 readers

But like litso said it's better to start your own blog so you have other things to show to interested readers. Then you can also promote them on tutorial site like pixel2life.com, tutorialized.com or cmstutorials.org.

Answer (score 2):

Smashingmagazine.com is one of the best out there, and they have ridiculous traffic numbers to help boost your viewers in a hurry.

Answer (score 1):

> "just need to refresh it a little bit"

If your own website is stale, I'd suggest that you contribute to an existing site or service as getting traffic needs a site to be kept up-to-date otherwise you'll fall from search engine rankings that give weighting to 'freshness' of a page/site.

As soon as someone else scrapes your tutorial text, which *will* happen eventually, they'll be a higher search hit than your site if they simply make changes to the front page more regularly than you do.

The other thing you could do is write an eBook or an iBook, since the content is harder to scrape and you don't need to build up a whole website.